# My Android JellyBean Lenovo A600e stuck repeatedly reboots when on

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, reboot

My phone misbehaved last evening and went on to show that my internal sd card is faulty. It gave me the option to format, which I did.

After that I realised that some apps are in my internal sd card. Now I believe that some of those apps getting removed due to formatting is the reason why the phone is crippled. Now I can't see which apps/components are missing, for, by the time I open any app, the phone reboots. However the reason can be anything, I am not sure. I even tried removing and re-inserting the sd card. Please help.

P.S.: I have now switched my phone off so that the battery doesn't get drained and I can debug the phone.

Comment: If an app misses parts that were on SDCard before, this might cause the app to crash – but shouldn't cause the device to reboot. Things you could try: Boot into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info). Here no user apps should be executed. In there, go to *Settings→Apps*, chose the "Downloaded" tab, and walk through the list to see what was moved to SDCard. Re-Install those apps. When in doubt, re-install them all. Boot to recovery, and chose to "wipe cache". Report back whether this helped.

Comment: Well, it leaves hardly 10-15 seconds between successive reboots, which doesn't even allow me to try what you said :-(

Comment: It does so even in safe mode, and even after you wiped cache? That probably leaves you with a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) as the only option.